# Why is it necessary to initialize the variable before if condition

Tags: java, variables

The following java code throws an exception: c not initialised.

```
int i = 4;
int c;
if (i == 4) c = 1;
if (i != 4) c = 2;
System.out.println(c);
```

If the code executes line by line, then why we need to initialise beforehand?

Comment: Do you expect the compiler to deduce that at least one of those `if` statements will execute? If so, I suggest you revise your expectations. Note that if you change it to `if (i == 4) { c = 1; } else { c = 2; }` then it'll be fine.

Comment: because theoretically it is possible for variable `i` to change its values between `if` conditions

Comment: The compiler simply isn't smart enough and doesn't analyze your code deep enough to understand that one of the if statements has to be true. So it thinks there is a possibility that none of your initialization statements is reached before you try to print the variable. If you change your double if statements to an `if (i==4) { c=1; } else { c=2; }` the compiler will understand that either the if or the else will be entered and you won't have that problem.

Comment: @IłyaBursov: No, it isn't possible when it's a local variable - but the language does not attempt to require the compiler to work out when multiple conditions cover all aspects.

Comment: Throws an exception?  Or won't compile?

Comment: BTW it is not too hard to have the value changed in-between, for example by setting a conditional break-point where the condition changes the value of `i` as side-effect (maybe also with some byte-code manipulating framework)

Comment: please study scope of states